# How to use external audio input (aux) on Mac?

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone, input-source, recording

I am trying to get an external sound source (a handheld FRS radio/Walkie Talkie with an 3.5mm output) working as an input (microphone) on my Mac (maxOS Monterey 12.4, MBP 16" 2021, M1 chip). Supposedly, the 3.5mm port on the Mac can serve as an input as well.

However, when I plug the 3.5mm aux cable into my Mac, it is recognized as external headphones, not an external microphone.

Some older blogs posts referred to a System Preferences "Use audio port for:" where you could reverse the audio direction. But it seems like that option does not exist anymore on newer MacOS versions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since 2015. MacBooks have had their line in ports phased out.  The 3.5mm jack is now just a headphone (ear phones and microphone) jack.